# Не выходит вызвать метод из Activity в фрагменте

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-fragment

В методе не выходит вызвать метод из `Activity` в фрагменте через код:

`new ActivityOne().addString(myString.getText().toString());`

Метод принимает строку через аргументы метода. Вот код метода `onClick` (при котором происходят все действия).

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText myString = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1);
        new ActivityOne().addString(myString.getText().toString());
        dismiss();
    }
```

Что тут не так и как вызвать метод?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод только что созданного экземпляра класса активити, тогда как вам надо вызывать метод действующей активити. Следовательно, вам надо сначала получить ссылку на действующую активити и уже на ней вызывать её метод.

```
//вместо new ActivityOne().addString(myString.getText().toString()); надо
//получить ссылку на активити из фрагмента. В классе фрагмента пишем:
ActivityOne actOne=(ActivityOne)getActivity();
//теперь, имея ссылку на действующую активити можно что-то с ней сделать
actOne.addString(myString.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Не работает. Вылетает на ``actOne.addString(myString.getText().toString());``

Comment: Вылетает с какой ошибкой? И таки зачем же вы принимаете ответ до проверки, работает ли он? =)

Comment: Может я не совсем Вас понял, но с ошибкой "В приложении произошла ошибка". Просто привык, что Вы сразу правильный ответ даете =)

Comment: Отладчик не выдаёт ошибки на языке Ленина. Это вы, видать, сами где-то ошибку поймали и вывели это сообщение. Без stackTace помочь не смогу. А ответ мой точно правильный. По крайней мере в контексте вашего вопроса. =)